# How can I recognise a Kotlin data class during annotation processing?

Tags: kotlin, annotations, kapt

I want to generate code for every data class using KAPT. Is there any reliable way of recognising a data class using the `javax.lang.model` API?

Answer (score 0):

In your kapt processing code it is possible to filter data classes

```
.getElementsAnnotatedWith(YourAnnotation::class)
.filter { it::class.isData }
.forEach {
    yourAction()
}
```

Comment: I think that the type of `it::class` is `Element` here, not the type of my (potentially) data class?